# How to make a loading with a progress bar in code Push?

Tags: typescript, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

Hello everyone i'm trying to make a styled updating in code push.
i want the application to follow these steps:

1. when the update start i want to show a loading ;
2. when the update is updating i want to show a screen with a text (" Updating ") and under it a progress bar with the percentage of update;

In my code i insert codepush update in App.tsx and tryied to dysplay with console logs only if the switch state was working but it didn't .

thank you in avance for your help i'm sorry but i dindn't fully undestand the codepush's documentation.

here is my code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import Navigation from './navigation';
import codePush from 'react-native-code-push';
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const codePushStatusDidChange = (status: any) => {
      switch (status) {
        case codePush.SyncStatus.CHECKING_FOR_UPDATE:
          console.log('Checking for updates.');
          break;
        case codePush.SyncStatus.DOWNLOADING_PACKAGE:
          console.log('Downloading package.');
          break;
        case codePush.SyncStatus.INSTALLING_UPDATE:
          console.log('Installing update.');
          break;
        case codePush.SyncStatus.UP_TO_DATE:
          console.log('Up-to-date.');
          break;
        case codePush.SyncStatus.UPDATE_INSTALLED:
          console.log('Update installed.');
          break;
      }
    };

    const codePushDownloadDidProgress = (progress: {
      receivedBytes: string;
      totalBytes: string;
    }) => {
      console.log(
        progress.receivedBytes + ' of ' + progress.totalBytes + ' received.',
      );
    };
    const syncImmediate = () => {
      console.log('synced');
      codePush.sync(
        {
          checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_START,
          installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE,
          updateDialog: {
            appendReleaseDescription: true,
            optionalUpdateMessage: 'Updates here..',
            title: 'New Updates',
            optionalInstallButtonLabel: 'Yes',
            optionalIgnoreButtonLabel: 'No',
          },
        },
        codePushStatusDidChange,
        codePushDownloadDidProgress,
      );
    };
    syncImmediate();
  });
  return (
    <>
      <Navigation />
    </>
  );
}

App = codePush(App);
```

Answer (score -3):

you can think of the python package `tqdm`
[Project PyPi and examples](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/)

Comment: Completely unrelated to "React native codepush"